# common terms problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Does anyone have an idea in finding common terms of two following sequences?
\begin{matrix} x_0=2,x_1=12, x_{n+1}=6x_n-x_{n-1} \\ x'_0=8,x'_1=144,x'_{n+1}=18x'_n-x'_{n-1}\end{matrix}
What is the most general method to find the common terms of two given sequences?

Thanks in advanced.

Sorry. Edited.

Comment: What is the subsequence of two given sequences?

Comment: @J.J yes, I do not know what the OP is referring to

Comment: a common subsequence, like he stated in the title I presume. as for the question: one way to do that would be to find explicit expressions for both of those sequences, but there might be a more efficient way in this particular case

Comment: So because the sequences are increasing, we are looking for the intersection of the sets $\{x_k : k \ge 0\}$ and $\{x'_k : k \ge 0\}$?

Comment: well, not so much, you loose some information when you consider sets instead of sequences

Comment: @mm-aops: Not when the sequences are (should have written "strictly") increasing.

Comment: right, sorry, I've missed that part of your comment

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking for $m$ such that $x_m=x_m'$? or are you asking for $j$ and $k$ such that $x_j=x_k'$?

Answer (score 0):

Under the given initial values, the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=6x_n-x_{n-1}$ has the solution $$\color{Blue}{x_n=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(3+2\sqrt{2})^{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(3-2\sqrt{2})^{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh(2(n+1) \ln(1+\sqrt{2})).}$$
Similarly, the recurrence relation $y_{n+1}=18y_n-y_{n-1}, y_0=8, y_1=144$ has the solution
$$\color{Purple}{y_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(9+4\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(9-4\sqrt{5})^{n+1}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\sinh(2(n+1) \ln(2+\sqrt{5})).}$$ It is an unfortunate that we don't have a notation for $\sinh$ in a base different from $e$ :). Observe that the second sequence grows quite faster than first one. Therefor there will be no positive integer $n$ such that $x_n=y_n.$ In fact, even there are no such reals except $n=-1.$

[image]

However, (as @GerryMyerson pointed out in a comment) finding pairs $(m, n)$ such that $x_m=y_n$ is a bit difficult problem.

Comment: Oh, I have missed something here ! I want to find the common terms of two given sequence. So sorry. My poor English. Your equation might be for positive integer m and n.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the solution :D

Comment: And that was the most interesting part of problem ! Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: Finding terms in both of a pair of recurrence sequences can be a difficult problem. See for example http://dml.cz/dmlcz/137484 and the references there.